# Разбить выборку на сегменты определенной длины

Tags: sql-server

Допустим, есть выборка из 99 записей и надо ее разбить на сегменты определенной длины, допустим 25.

В выборке есть ключ.

Пример стартовых данных:

ID

1

2

3

4

5

После разбиение по 2 будет так:

ID PAGE

1  1

2  1

3  2

4  2

5  3

Это легко делается через курсор. Однако, можно ли это сделать без курсора в MS SQL 2008 r2?

Comment: `ntile(50) over (order by id)` ?

Comment: @teran, хм... Надо попробовать.

Comment: или какое нить `dense_rank() over (order by rn/2)`, где rn это номер строки?

Comment: @teran а что такое rn? Это результат другой оконной функции?

Comment: @iluxa1810 row_number

Comment: ну коли у вас есть выборка в 99 элементов, и то пронумеровать с помощью `row_number()` вы ее можете. потом номер можно нацело делить

Comment: @teran , вроде, ntile сработал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дабы подытожить комментарии, возьмем тестовый пример данных из 100 последовательных номеров (предполагаем что они не такие уж и последовательные)

```
WITH dataset AS (   
    select 1  as id
    union all
    select id+1 from dataset where id < 100
)
select * from dataset;
```

Далее из числа ранжирующих функций можем использовать `ntile(N)`, который делит выборку на `N` групп. То есть чтобы 100 строк разбить по 2, надо разделить на 50 групп. Для общего случая можно определить это число подзапросом:

```
SELECTid, ntile( 
                (select count(id)/2 from dataset) 
            ) over (order by id)
FROM dataset;
```

и результат

```
id          
----------- --------------------
1           1
2           1
3           2
4           2
5           3
6           3
7           4
```

Либо второй вариант - использовать функцию `dense_rank()`, а для ранжирования взять номера строк, поделив их нацело на желаемое число элементов в группе:

```
.....
, nums AS (
    SELECT id
         , (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) -1) AS rn
    FROM dataset
)
SELECT id, dense_rank() OVER ( ORDER BY rn/2)
FROM nums
```